# Change span position when resized : Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

In Twitter Bootstrap,I used span5 and span7 in a row.When I re-size the browser to mobile layout,the span5 stays on top and the span7 goes below span5. I want the span7 to stay on top and span5 to go below it.

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve something like this, you'll need to manipulate your DOM structure a bit.  I would first recommend trying to "hack" the page structure if at all possible.  By this I mean; would it be possible to put the `span7` first in the DOM, then float the `span7` right and the `span5` left?  That would allow you to show them in the correct order at any screen size, and you could fix the floats using a media query at the desired size.

Otherwise, this sounds like a job for jQuery.  jQuery would allow you to manipulate DOM elements on the fly, you could easily write a script which at a certain window width juggles the DOM position of two elements.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse their order in the DOM tree to have:

```
<div class="span7"></div>
<div class="span5"></div>
```

... and then set `float: right` for both span5 and span7. You can use a specific CSS class name for that.

This way, on larger displays you'll have span5 to the left and span7 to the right, and on mobiles span7 above and span5 bellow.